# Chances of getting visa

Tags: usa, visa, nepal

My friend got selected for the DV Lottery. What is chance of getting visa if he don't have academic qualification and does not meet the job zone and range but has 5 years experience as a cook?

Comment: Does he have a high school diploma or equivalent? If he does, then work experience does not matter.

Comment: No he don't have

Comment: In that case it sounds like he is not qualified to proceed with the process.  Is there any way for him to acquire a high school diploma or the equivalent?  In case of cultural misunderstanding, I would add that a high school diploma is the credential that one normally qualifies for after 12 years of school, usually from age 6 to age 17 or 18.